# change specific text color in java

Tags: java, string, swing, text, colors

i am wondering how can i change a specific text color in a sentence?

lets say HELLO WORLD...i wanted to change the WORLD into red color without altering the font color of HELLO..same exact thing on how to change the WORLD in to bold

i wanted to set these string in to a jtextarea but all i can find is something like this

```
JTextArea textbox = new JTextArea("hello world");
textbox.setForeground(Color.red)
```

these makes the whole sentence into red instead of only making WORLD into red?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) from the Oracle documentation on text components. A `JTextArea` will accept styling, but it will always apply styling across its entire contents. However, if you were to use a `JTextPane`, you could create any styling you wanted in your text using HTML.

Code to back up assertion:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;

public class StyleTestApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("test");
        //f.getContentPane().add(new JTextArea("<html>HELLO <font size=\"3\" face=\"verdana\" color=\"red\">WORLD</font></html>"));
        final JTextPane p = new JTextPane();
        // the HTMLEditorKit is not enabled by default in the JTextPane class.
        p.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
        p.setText("<html>HELLO <font size=\"3\" face=\"verdana\" color=\"red\">WORLD</font></html>");
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```