# Swing - Is it possible to set the font color of 'specific' text within a JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts, awt

I have a JTable where one column displays values in the following format:

```
423545(50),[7568787(50)],53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(50),[8021947(50)]
```

I am wondering if it is possible to display the values within square brackets in RED?

I have been googling around for the last few days and have found several examples showing how to set the 'background' of a cell but not really how to change the font of a cell especially not a specific part of the text.

```
public class myTableCellRenderer
       extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                                 Object value,
                                                 boolean isSelected,
                                                 boolean hasFocus,
                                                 int row,
                                                 int column) {
    Component c = 
      super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                                          isSelected, hasFocus,
                                          row, column);

    if (column == 3) {
       c.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
       c.setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    return c;
  }
```

Is it really possible to change part of the text to be a different color (i.e. the text that is within the square brackets).

### Edit

The text i showed as an example is the actual text shown in the table cell (the comma separators are not representing columns). The text displayed in the cell is a comma separated string that i display on the table in column 3.

As an example the table could look like this

```
product_id |product_name| invoice_numbers
12         |    Books   | 423545(50),[7568787(50)],53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(50),[8021947(50)]
323        |    Videos  | 423545(50),[7568787(50)],53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(50),[8021947(50)]
4434       |    Music   | 423545(50),[7568787(50)],53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(50),[8021947(50)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You must use a Cell renderer combined with HTML.

Here is a small demo example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable2 {

    class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component tableCellRendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (value instanceof String) {
                String string = (String) value;
                if (string.indexOf('[') > -1) {
                    setText(getHTML(string));
                }
            }
            return tableCellRendererComponent;
        }

        private String getHTML(String string) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("<html>");
            int index = 0;
            while (index < string.length()) {
                int next = string.indexOf('[', index);
                if (next > -1) {
                    int end = string.indexOf(']', next);
                    if (end > -1) {
                        next++;
                        sb.append(string.substring(index, next));
                        sb.append("<span style=\"color: red;\">");
                        sb.append(string.substring(next, end));
                        sb.append("</span>");
                        index = end;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            sb.append(string.substring(index, string.length()));
            sb.append("</html>");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            model.addColumn("Col-" + (i + 1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                row.add("423545(50),[7568787(50)],53654656,2021947(50),[021947],2021947(50),[8021947(50)]");
            }
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyCellRenderer());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTable2.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable2().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for [Cell render](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html)

How to proceed:

1. get the default cell render component using  `getTableCellRendererComponent()` function with the appropriate parameters.
2. parse the text of the cell and apply your formatting using `setForeground()` function.

Comment: Yet, this will set the whole cell color, not just the part within '[' ']'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399823/change-specific-text-color-in-java check that question.

Comment: Or just have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14547140/928711) ;-)

Comment: that's same concept . using the html toolkit. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Is it really possible to change part of the text to be a different color
```

yes is possible, for

- simple highlighter is possible with `JTextField/JTextArea`  as `Renderers component`
- multiple of the `Highlighter` have to look for `JTextPane` as `Renderers component`
- (easier of ways) you can to formatting cell by using `Html` (todays `Java up to Html3.2`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. 
**EDIT**
First you need to create a subclass of `DefaultTableCellRenderer` where you override `getTableCellRendererComponent` method to render the desired column according to your need.
And then change the renderer for that column by the subclass of `DefaultTableCellRenderer`. 
Here is the example to achieve this task:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TableExample extends JFrame
{
    JTable myTable ;
    Object[][] data= {
                    {"34","[56],987,[(56)]"},
                    {"5098","345,([{78}])"},
                    {"567","4312"}
                };
    Object[] col = {"First","Second"};
    public TableExample()
    {
        super("CellRendererExample");
    }
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        myTable = new JTable(data,col);
        myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(myTable);
        getContentPane().add(jsp);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
    {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object oValue, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
        {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, oValue,isSelected, hasFocus,row, column);
            String value = (String)oValue;
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append("<HTML><BODY>");
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(value,",");
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                int index = token.indexOf("[");
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    sBuilder.append(token.substring(0,index));
                    int lastIndex = token.lastIndexOf(']');
                    String subValue = token.substring(index + 1,lastIndex);
                    sBuilder.append("[<FONT color = red>"+subValue+"</FONT>]");
                    if (lastIndex < token.length() -1)
                    {
                        sBuilder.append(token.substring(lastIndex+1,token.length()));
                    }
                    sBuilder.append(",");
                }
                else
                {
                    sBuilder.append(token+",");
                }
            }
            if (sBuilder.lastIndexOf(",") == sBuilder.length() - 1)
            {
                sBuilder.deleteCharAt(sBuilder.length() - 1 );
            }
            sBuilder.append("</BODY></HTML>");
            value = sBuilder.toString(); ;
            JLabel label =(JLabel)c;
            label.setText(value);
            return label;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                TableExample tae = new TableExample();
                tae.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Will this not change the font for all the text in that specific cell? It does check that the text contains the characters [ and ] but wouldn't c.setForeground set the foreground for everything within that cell?

Comment: -1 You should use an appropriate TableCellRenderer. and also -1 because it will set everything in red, not just the  value between brackets

Comment: @ziggy My Mistake . I misunderstood your Question. See my Edit.

Comment: @kleopatra May i know which naming convention did i miss??

Comment: `myTableCellRenderer ` should be `MyTableCellRenderer`: notice the capital "M" at the beginning. Also, you should not override `getCellRenderer` but actually access `setDefaultRenderer` or `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer)`. Overriding methods must be used when you add functionality.

Comment: Rather use `StringBuilder` than `StringBuffer`. Using string concatenation ('+') when you have already a StringBuilder/StringBuffer is counterproductive, always use `append()`. Your parsing code is incorrect since you call `value = value + "</BODY></HTML>";` within the loop, resulting in having `"</BODY></HTML>"` several time in the text.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: Thanks for the notable points. There were more to watch in previous code. It is updated now..