# Change colour of word in a java string sentence

Tags: java

Lets say I have a string - is it possible to change the colour of a specific word instead of the whole string?

```
String = "Jim likes games and cars";
```

How would I go about changing the colour of the word "games" to red?

Right now `setFontColor(Color.red);`changes the colour of the entire string.

This is for a command line based application

Comment: In where, a terminal, a javafx UI, a web UI, other ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change specific text color in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399823/change-specific-text-color-in-java)

Comment: @azro its for console application